# transcation take to long on cleos push action in EOS 1.0.2

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, block-producer, nodeos

Exception encountered while processing chain.push_transaction: 3040005 expired_tx_exception: Expired Transaction
transaction has expired, expiration is 2018-06-12T12:30:04 and pending block time is 2018-06-12T12:30:04.500
    {"trx.expiration":"2018-06-12T12:30:04","pending_block_time":"2018-06-12T12:30:04.500"}
    thread-0  controller.cpp:1350 validate_expiration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by managing our smart contract ,Execution of any action of smart contract  maximum transaction is 150ms,Our action takes more than 150 ms ,we have modified smart contract in such way that the action is executing before 150ms

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this issue in testing from time to time on the first action after deploying a contract.  The first action will fail with a timeout, but reissuing the transaction allows it (and all subsequent transactions) to succeed.